# Adding an element inside of an element in a Todolist

Tags: javascript

I am creating a to-do list, I can create new todos inside of my Li but I can't get it to create a button(later I would like to add a span) inside of my Li as well, I want that button to be a delete button. (aka when I add a new todo, I want there to be a button on the right side of that new todo)

```
<button onclick="addNewFunc()"> add</button>
<input type="text" class="input">
<ul>
    <li>1</li> 
    <li><span>X </span>2</li>
</ul>

let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

let addNewFunc = function () {
    let addNew = document.createElement("li");
    let createBtn = document.createElement("button");
    let name = ul.appendChild(addNew);    
    name.textContent = input.value;
    input.value = ""
};

(function(){
    input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            addNewFunc();

        }
    })
}());
```

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: It's the same as adding a `<li>` to the `<ul>`